# Discord.JS TypeError: ping is not a function

Tags: discord.js, typeerror

I am trying to make a command for my bot to ping Minecraft servers such as Hypixel, but whenever I run the bot and type in the command I get this:

```
ping('mc.hypixel.net', 25565, (error, response) =>{
            ^

TypeError: ping is not a function
```

This is my code:

```js
client.on('message', message =>{

    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ')

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'mc':
            ping('mc.hypixel.net', 25565, (error, response) =>{
                if (error) throw error
            
                console.log(response)
            })
        break
    }



})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.js` doesn't support such a command, but there is other package that does! Just install `minecraft-server-util` with `npm i minecraft-server-util`

after that put this in your code

```js
const { ping } = require('minecraft-server-util');
```

and then

```js
//use ping command
 ping(<name of the server>, { port: 25565 })
.then((response) => {

//we are sending a response to the channel where command was initiated
       return message.channel.send(response);
    })
    

//we are catching an eventual error
    .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you did but now my error is: "ping(mc.hypixel.net, { port: 25565 })
                                                                               ^

ReferenceError: mc is not defined"

Comment: Oh you have to put it in `" "`, so `"mc.hypixel.net"`

Comment: Now it says "ping("mc.hypixel.net", { port: 25565 })
                    ^

TypeError: ping is not a function" :/

Comment: Try `"play.hypixel.net"` instead of `"mc.hypixel.net"`

Comment: Still the same thing :(